# Reverse pagination with kaminari?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I am using [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) 0.13.0 with [RubyOnRails](http://rubyonrails.org/) 3.2.8.

Lets assume I have a default ordering of my elements by `crated_at`, I have `8` elements in my list `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}` and I paginate them `3` per page.

By default kaminari will create the following page links `1, 2, 3` linking to `{h, g}`, `{f, e, d}`, `{c, b, a}`.

**How do I make kaminari create the page links in reverse order?** I want it to produce the links in reverse order `3, 2, 1` still linking to reverse ordered elements `{h, g}`, `{f, e, d}`, `{c, b, a}`.

**A bit context on the problem I am trying to solve:**

I order elements on pages by created_at. I want to have the elements stay on the same page forever. If I do not use reverse pagination, every time I add new elements the page contents change. So in the above example with default kaminari behaviour if I added more elements to the list `{i, j}` then the `1st` page would contain `{j, i, h}`, not `{h, g}` as it used to. The `2nd` page would contain `{g, f, e}` not `{f, e, d}` as it used to, etc...
This is bad for bookmaking , SEO, etc.

If I had the described above reverse page numbering, then the `1st` page would still have `{c, b, a}`, `3rd` page would be updated with the new element to `{i, h, g}` and there would be a new page 4 with one element `{j}`.

Comment: Please upgrade to Rails 3.2.11 ASAP

Comment: Normally this problem is solved by having the links say "Older Posts" or "Next Page". Is that something you're open to?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I am not sure I understand what you mean. Older posts and next page links have nothing to do with the problem I described above. They are just helpers, the problem of having different data apearing on the same pages stays.

Comment: Sure, no worries then. I think you'll have to edit the kaminari source or go non-kaminari for this. This is not the problem that most anyone ever tries to solve.

Comment: hey I've got a post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738045/reverse-pagination-with-kaminari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
def index
  users_scope = Users.order(:whateva)
  @users = reverse_paginate(users_scope, params[:page])
end

def reverse_paginate(scope, page)
  if page
    page_number = page
  else 
    page_number = Kaminari.paginate_array(scope.reverse).page(1).per(10).num_pages
  end
  Kaminari.paginate_array(scope.reverse).page(page_number).per(10).reverse!
end
```

You need to update the kaminari page view `_page.html.erb` and add `?page=1` to the url:

```
   url = "#{url}?page=1" if page.number == 1
   link_to_unless page.current?, page.number, url, opts = {:remote => remote, :rel => page.next? ? 'next' : page.prev? ? 'prev' : nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This answer is cross-posted from [another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738045/reverse-pagination-with-kaminari).*

There's a good example repo on Github called [reverse_kaminari](https://github.com/Djo/reverse_kaminari) on github. It suggests an implementation along these lines [(Source)](https://github.com/Djo/reverse_kaminari/blob/master/app/controllers/cities_controller.rb).

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @cities = prepare_cities City.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  private

  def prepare_cities(scope)
    @per_page = City.default_per_page
    total_count = scope.count
    rest_count = total_count > @per_page ? (total_count % @per_page) : 0
    @num_pages = total_count > @per_page ? (total_count / @per_page) : 1

    if params[:page]
      offset = params[:page].sub(/-.*/, '').to_i
      current_page = @num_pages - (offset - 1) / @per_page
      scope.page(current_page).per(@per_page).padding(rest_count)
    else
      scope.page(1).per(@per_page + rest_count)
    end
  end

end
```

All credits go to [Andrew Djoga](https://github.com/Djo). He also hosted the app as [a working demo](http://reverse-kaminari.heroku.com/).

Answer (score 0):

`Kaminary.paginate_array` does not produce query with offset and limit. For optimization reason, you shouldn't use this.

Posted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22897591/479407).